# Requiring Tags upon EC2 Instance Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-iam, tagging

I am trying to create a situation where upon creation of an EC2 instance, it forces you to add tags to the instance and will not let you create it unless that specific tag key is used.

I have tried a number of examples from both the AWS site and from SO and everything that I have tried in policy simulator has allowed me to create an instance without having tags added.

This is the policy that I am currently using

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowToDescribeAll",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:Describe*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstances",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::image/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*::snapshot/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:subnet/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:network-interface/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:security-group/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:key-pair/*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRunInstancesWithRestrictions",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateVolume",
                "ec2:RunInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:RequestTag/key1": "value1",
                    "aws:RequestTag/key2": "value2"
                },
                "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                    "aws:TagKeys": [
                        "requiredKey"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCreateTagsOnlyLaunching",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:volume/*",
                "arn:aws:ec2:*:*:instance/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:CreateAction": "RunInstances"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This specific user that I am trying to use it under has AmazonEC2FullAccess, IAMFullAccess, and the above permission added to their account.

Comment: Since you are only granting permissions (using Allow), there is no reason why an identity with AmazonEC2FullAccess should not be able to launch instances without the tags assigned. You should change the Effect to "Deny" and the "ForAllValues:StringEquals" condition operator to "ForAllValues:StringNotEquals". The reason behind this is: You must create an explicit deny for a user which already has a broad set of permissions assigned.

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51942696/2732674 ?